# how to capture network traffic in the pcap file using tcpdump command?

Tags: websocket, tcpdump

I want to capture network trafic of my application using tcpdump command.

I'm implemented the Websocket client and server, in which server is sending messages to the connected clients continously. So in that scenario I just want to capture this messages in one pcap file.

previously I used this command which is not working properly :

`sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 -s0 -w mycap.pcap`

Can anyone told me how to capture such type of network traffic  using tcpdump command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.

Are you receiving an error, or is your file "mycap.pcap" empty?

If your file is unexpectedly empty, check if you have another interface that is receiving the traffic.

If all else fails, try -i any for the interface.

Comment: **mycap.pcap** file contains data but I'm unable to find the data which server sending to clients.

Comment: Got it...Problem of any & eth0...when I give any in the command then it will showing in good manner. But still have one doubt, why it is not coming on default eth0 interface and on which interface it is coming?

Comment: If your client and server are on the same machine, it won't make it out eth0.

Comment: You know reason behind that? why It is like that can you provide me links or sample for that?

Comment: They are communicating over your loopback interface, or lo from ifconfig.  If the client and server are on the same machine, they can communicate over this interface  via the loopback ip 127.0.0.1.  I'm on mobile, but will link something later.